# Intuition for Sobol Indices

Tags: sensitivity-analysis

I have recently been learning about Sobol indices and have found them quite informative. However, as I have explored them I have encoutnered situations where I have found them counter intuitive and in fact more misleading than helpful.

I am lead to assume that this must be a misconception on my part, so perhaps somebody could shed some light on this for me?

For our considerations let $ X,Y \sim \mathcal N(0,1) $ be standard normally distribution and consider a model $ Z = f(X,Y) $.

**Scenario (1):** Let $ f(X,Y) = aX+bY $, then the Sobol indices are $ S_X = \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2} $, $ S_Y = \frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2} $ and $ S_{XY} = 0 $, which makes a lot of sense each of them contributing a fraction of the variance proportional to their own variance.

**Scenario (2):** Let $ f(X,Y) = XY $, then the Sobol indices are $ S_X = S_Y = 0 $ and $ S_{XY} = 1 $, which again makes sense. All variation is contributed by their combination.

**Scenario (3):** Let $ f(X,Y) = X^2Y $. Now it gets counter-intuitive to me. Here the Sobol indices are $ S_X = 0 $, $ S_Y = \frac13 $ and $ S_{XY} = \frac23 $. I can compute the indices, no problem, but the way I see it $ X $ is much more significant to the variance than $ Y $ here, which is not clear from the indices at all. In fact, they kind of seem to tell the opposite story.

Of course, $ S_X = 0 $ in **(3)** is due to it being proportional to $ \mathbb E_Y[f(X,Y)] = 0 $, so $ f(X,Y) = X^kY $ for all $ k > 0 $ has $ S_X = 0 $.

What exactly am I supposed to take away from scenario **(3)**? And if this is kind of an artifact of the setup, how am I supposed to identify such an issue in another setting where the model $ f $ is way more obscure? or straight up black box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$ is much more significant to the variance than $$

The Sobol indices belong to a specific category of **Sensitivity Analysis** called **Global Sensitivity Analysis** (GSA). GSA computes sensitivity indices by taking into account for the model $f(X,Y)$ and the probability distributions of the input random variables $X$ and $Y$. The above statement focuses solely on the model and does not account for the input distributions.

### Example

Let us shift the mean of the distributions and compute the Sobol indices (numerically) once again for **scenario (3)**.

**Case 0**: $X, Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$

As expected: $S_X \approx 0.00 , S_Y \approx 0.33 $ and $S_{XY} \approx 0.66$.

**Case 1**: $X, Y \sim \mathcal{N}(1,1)$

We obtain: $S_X \approx 0.37 , S_Y \approx 0.25 $ and $S_{XY} \approx 0.37$.

**Case 2**: $X, Y \sim \mathcal{N}(100,1)$

We obtain: $S_X \approx 0.79 , S_Y \approx 0.20 $ and $S_{XY} \approx 0$.

### Intuition

For **Case 0**: $X, Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, most of the probability mass ($\sim 68 \%$) of the random variables is between $[-1, 1]$. Therefore $X^2$ will be smaller than $Y$ "most" of the time. Since the values of $X$ are small, the effect of their variance is also small. As the probability mass shifts to higher values in **Case 1** and **Case 2**, the values of $X$ increase and their variance naturally has a larger contribution to the overall variance of $f(X,Y)$ and we see that the first order index $S_X$ increases.